# Why is my Program not giving me an output?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

```
What am I missing, My program won't give me any outputs. I am also getting an error "constructor class cannot applied given types" like that.
```

Our lesson is all about Depth First Search and Binary graph but I made a mistake not to attend class, so now I'm regretting it. Please someone help me.

I can't add some details cause I really don't know how this program works though so I'm really really sorry.

```
public class MainDriver{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph mygraph = new Graph(22);
        mygraph.addEdge(1,2);
        mygraph.addEdge(2,4);
        mygraph.addEdge(2,5);
        mygraph.addEdge(4,8);
        mygraph.addEdge(4,9);
        mygraph.addEdge(8,16);
        mygraph.addEdge(8,17);
        mygraph.addEdge(9,18);
        mygraph.addEdge(9,19);
        mygraph.addEdge(5,10);
        mygraph.addEdge(5,11);
        mygraph.addEdge(10,20);
        mygraph.addEdge(10,21);
        mygraph.addEdge(1,3);
        mygraph.addEdge(3,6);
        mygraph.addEdge(3,7);
        mygraph.addEdge(6,12);
        mygraph.addEdge(6,13);
        mygraph.addEdge(7,14);
        mygraph.addEdge(7,15);


    }

     DepthFirstSearch dfs = new DepthFirstSearch(G,v );



}


----------

Here's my subclass

public class DepthFirstSearch{

private boolean[] marked;
private int count;

public DepthFirstSearch(Graph G, int s) {
    marked = new boolean[G.getV()];
    dfs(G, s);


}




private void dfs(Graph G, int v) {

    marked[v] = true;
    System.out.print(v);
    count++;

    for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
        if (!marked[w]) {
            dfs(G, w);
        }

    }


}

public boolean marked(int w) {
    return marked[w];

}


public int count() {
    return count;
}

}
```

Comment: Please edit this properly. It's hard for us to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *Program* does not output anything, because your *code* does not output anything.

I can only assume you are supposed to implement your own "Printing" or "Drawing" functionality.

If you want to see something (anything) on output, just do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("START");

    Graph mygraph = new Graph(22);
    mygraph.addEdge(1,2);
    ...

    mygraph.addEdge(7,15);
    System.out.println("END");

}
```

You should get the output:

```
START
END
```

Comment: Can you help me program? It's all about Depth First Search, We have to get any graph from the internet that has 20+ vertices and we should have an output like 0 2 4 1 5 "displaying vertices it has registered"